# "Login Expires After Inactivity" to "Never Expires" for a particular user in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio, sfmc-business-unit

Can I change `"Login Expires After Inactivity"` to `"Never Expires"` for a particular user(not to all) in marketing cloud ?
I found an option in

> Setup->Security setting->Login Expires After Inactivity (in Username
> and Logins)

but that setting is for all users or for a particular user?

Comment: This is only able to be applied globally

Answer (score 0):

The Login Expires After Inactivity setting prevents a user from logging in to the account after not logging in for several days. For example, if the value is 90 days and a user doesn’t log in for 90 days, you must reset the user login information. This setting helps prevent unauthorized users from exploiting old accounts.
This applies to all the users. If you want the password to never expire for a particular user, e.g. API integration user, set the user as API user and set *Exclude API Users From Password Expiration* to YES in *Setup > security Settings*